# TeamCity, "Transferring repository sources: n.n Mb so far.."

Tags: teamcity

Our TeamCity transfers repository sources each time we build.

We have two build projects, one to our build/dev/stage-server and one to our production server. The transferring of repo sources started when we added the production project. It takes 30 minutes to build to the production server because of the transferring, very annoying.

Googling gives me nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to do this(some configs won't allow), set 'VCS Checkout Mode' on the 'Version Control Settings' page to 'Automatically on agent.' This will allow the checkout of the code to be faster.

I'm not quite sure if that's answering your question, but I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem this morning. Not sure of the underlying cause, but a simple restart of the server fixed it.